# Search textbox clears show all the data in to html table using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have HTML table when I first load the page showing all the data into HTML table
using PHP.I have implemented ajax and jquery for search it is working fine.It is showing matched data when matches else giving no results found message from ajax url file.But When I empty the textbox it is not showing all the rows.How to show If textbox empty All the records.I am new to jquery and ajax.Please any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

### HTML

```
<div class="scrollingTable result" style="width:100%;">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;padding-top:20px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Telephone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>GSTIN Number</th>
                        <th>Bankname</th>
                        <th>Account Number</th>
                        <th>IFSC Code</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php
              echo  $vndr_list;
              ?>
                      </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>



  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     var minlength = 1;
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
      if(minlength<value.length){
       //this is the table when loading first time showing all the data.
        $("#myTable").empty();
        $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {name :value},
        success: function(html){
        $("#myTable").prepend(html);
      }
      });
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Use jquery datatable, its a very good plugin for such kind of functionality. Check this fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/ebRXw/

Comment: ok thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 var minlength = 0;
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
  var value=$(this).val();

   //this is the table when loading first time showing all the data.

    $.ajax({
    url: "search.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name :value},
    success: function(html){
  $("#myTable tbody").empty();
    $("#myTable > tbody").html(html);
  }
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I would remove if(minlength